# QImage (or images generally) conversion to 3 1D arrays for RGB

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

A function that I am trying to conform to requires three 1-Dimensional arrays of type double[19200].  The following arrays are RGB arrays such that:

```
double r[19200]; // r
double g[19200]; // g
double b[19200]; // b
```

So far, I can extract pixel information from a QImage and populate the above arrays.

The problem is with testing.  I don't know how to do the inverse: **given the three 1-Dimensional arrays how do I create a new QImage from this data?**

I would like to verify that I am indeed getting the correct values.  (Things like column vs. row major order is giving me doubts). As a result, I am trying to construct an image a QImage from these three 1-D Dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand why you're having a problem if you managed to do it one way. The process is essentially the same:

```
for (int x=0; x<w; x++)
  for (int y=0; y<h; y++)
     image.setPixel(x,y, convertToRGB(r[x*w+y], ...);
```

Where `convertToRGB` is the inverse transform of what you to to convert and RGB value to your float values, supposing the image has dimension `w*h`. If you discover this is the wrong row-major/column major variant, just inverse it.

Since you gave no info about how you do the color space conversion, and we don't know if it's row-major or column-major either, can't help you much more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like QImage supports a couple of ways to load from pixel arrays.

```
QImage(const uchar *data, int width, int height, Format format)
bool QImage::loadFromData(const uchar *buf, int len, const char *format=0)
```

Using the first example, if you have the arrays you mention, then you will likely want to use the format QImage::Format_RGB888 (from qimage.h).

You will need to know the width and height yourself.

Finally you will want to repack your arrays into a single uchar* array

```
uchar* rgb_array = new uchar[19200+19200+19200];

for( int i = 0, j = 0; j < 19200; ++j )
{
    // here we convert from the double range 0..1 to the integer range 0..255
    rgb_array[i++] = r[j] * 255;
    rgb_array[i++] = g[j] * 255;
    rgb_array[i++] = b[j] * 255;
}

{
    QImage my_image( rgb_array, width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888 );

    // do stuff with my_image...
}

delete[] rgb_array; // note you need to hold onto this array while the image still exists
```